# Error via sending email through classic asp:

Tags: email, asp-classic, vbscript, gmail, cdo.message

I am trying to send email via classic asp but it gives me below error.

`CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'
The transport failed to connect to the server.
/hotemp/regnew.asp, line 507`

**Initially it was working fine**, suddenly it gives the above error. I googled but it didn’t help. Any suggestions on how to get over this. Thank you

My code below:

```
<%

 Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="myemail@gmail.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="password"

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update

Mail.Subject="Sending via classic asp"
Mail.From="abcdef@gmail.com"
Mail.To="wxyz@gmail.com"

Mail.TextBody="please fill the form" 
Mail.Send      ` line 507
Set Mail = Nothing

%>
```

Comment: According to Google, smtp.gmail.com has a limit: "In an effort to fight spam and prevent abuse, Google will temporarily disable your account if you send a message to more than 500 recipients or if you send a large number of undeliverable messages... Your account should be re-enabled within 24 hours."

Comment: I have never sent emails more than 30 or maybe 40 within the time frame of 24hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when code starts off working fine and then fails without any changes to the code being made, it's the result of something changing on the server.

I would hazard a guess that you've been sending either too many emails, or that gmail thinks your messages are a little spammy and has stopped accepting connections.

Usually when sending email from a web app like this, you're better off using the mail server your host provides you or signing up with a service that offers this sort of thing.

Comment: But I changed my sender email address and it is supposed to work fine but it doesn't.

Comment: Same Email address when i am using through asp.net c# it is working fine without any issue. Only when i try to send emails using classic ASP it is giving above error. Thank you